# How to show blue pin with dot (circle) in MKMapView in IPhone

Tags: iphone, mkmapview

my question may seem a bit complicated but let me clarify. i am using mkmapview , in this i want to show current user location with blue dot and circle , but this isn't really exactly what I wanted. As I am making an iPhone application,SInce I am new to map integration its getting difficult for me to do the same.IF any one can provide me a link for its demo or can explain me how to show user location with blue dot with circle on map then it would be of great help to me . Thanks in advance

Comment: its a default feature of MKMapView, Please set your mapView property showuserLocation to true and there you go ...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is one of properties of MKMapView class. Default value is No, so just set it to YES in your code.

Note that if you add a MapView on to your ViewController in Storyboard, look at the attribute inspector, by default has other annotations checked (Buildings, Points of Interest) on your MapView excepts User Location. It took me a while to find this, it feels like I am playing hide and seek, no sure why it so important to leave this unchecked.

```
self.mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
```

As [thexande](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4293021/thexande) mentioned, for swift3 you will have to set this to true:

```
self.mapView.showsUserLocation = true;
```

Comment: Set this to true for Swift 3.

Comment: @thexande yes for Swift 3 you need to set to true.

Comment: You can also set this via storyboard

Answer (score 6):

Add this to the top of the viewForAnnotation method:

```
if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
return nil;
```

The special user location annotation is of type MKUserLocation and returning nil in that case tells the map view to draw the default view for it which is the blue dot. and go in MKMapview property and check the show user location....

Answer (score 6):

**For SWIFT 3**

```
if (annotation.isKind(of: MKUserLocation.self)){
        return nil
    }
```

This will allow you to show a blue dot for your user's location in swift 3.

Put this code in the mapView viewFor annotation func

Answer (score 1):

Answer of @Ohmy is correct but in my program the case was different :

From iOS10 you need to add `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` or  `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` key in your app `Info.plist` based on your requirement.