# I need to show my location with the normal blue dot and another point with a different marker

Tags: swift, mapkit

I changed the design of a marker in the mapView, but in doing this I changed the marker of my location and it was not what I wanted. I just want to change the marker of MIT, and the one of my location to leave it only with the normal blue marker that appears on all maps.

Here I leave some code that could be failing.

```
mapView.register(MKMarkerAnnotationView.self,
                         forAnnotationViewWithReuseIdentifier: MKMapViewDefaultClusterAnnotationViewReuseIdentifier)
let mitCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -41.471373559102965, longitude: -72.94215917587279)
let mitAnnotation = SchoolAnnotation(coordinate: mitCoordinate, title: "MIT", subtitle: "mit - USA")

mapView.addAnnotation(mitAnnotation)
mapView.setRegion(mitAnnotation.region, animated: true)


extension BusinessViewController: MKMapViewDelegate {
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
        if let schoolAnnotationView
            = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: MKMapViewDefaultAnnotationViewReuseIdentifier) as? MKMarkerAnnotationView {
            schoolAnnotationView
            .animatesWhenAdded = true
            schoolAnnotationView
            .titleVisibility = .adaptive
            schoolAnnotationView
            .titleVisibility = .adaptive

            return schoolAnnotationView
        }

        return nil
    }
```

Here's an image:

[image]

Comment: This may be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14155389/how-to-show-blue-pin-with-dot-circle-in-mkmapview-in-iphone

Comment: Frakcool yes, but it does not show the blue dot, it shows the red marker like the other one that I edited

Comment: I am not sure what could be going wrong with your code, but this other [article](https://www.raywenderlich.com/548-mapkit-tutorial-getting-started) if you follow the tutorial, you might find something that you have(n't) done in your project configuration that may be breaking it. Try to look for the differences between it and your code. Suerte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your implementation of

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
```

does not look to see whether this `annotation` is your MIT annotation or your user location annotation. You need to start with an `if` condition and check that. If it's the user location, you return `nil` to get the default marker.