# Make user location visible on the map does not work

Tags: ios, swift, core-location

If I am running my code the rounded blue point isn't shown up on the map. user location visible on the map does not work. I can't find the problem for that. Anyone who can find the issue?

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class GPSNewBin: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {


    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
    @IBOutlet weak var zurueckButton: UIButton!

    var locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Ask for Authorisation from the User.
        self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

        // For use in foreground
        self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            locationManager.delegate = self
            locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        }
    }


    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        //guard let locValue: CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location?.coordinate else { return }
        let locValue: CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location!.coordinate
        print("locations = \(locValue.latitude) \(locValue.longitude)")
        let userLocation = locations.last
        let viewRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: (userLocation?.coordinate)!, latitudinalMeters: 600, longitudinalMeters: 600)
        self.mapView.setRegion(viewRegion, animated: true)
    }

}
```

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: see this for help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14155389/how-to-show-blue-pin-with-dot-circle-in-mkmapview-in-iphone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can enable user location from a storyboard:**

[image: mapView]

OR

**You can also enable it using code:**

```
mapView.showsUserLocation = true
```

Answer (score 0):

You must include following properties in Info.plist, without it your request for authorization will not work.

```
<key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>Message for AlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</string>

<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>Message for AlwaysUsageDescription</string>

<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>Message for WhenInUseUsageDescription</string>
```

Use following method for requesting authorization in `viewDidLoad`, it also takes in account when location services is denied to the app.

```
func checkLocationAuthorization(authorizationStatus: CLAuthorizationStatus? = nil) {
    switch (authorizationStatus ?? CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()) {
    case .authorizedAlways, .authorizedWhenInUse:
        mapView.showsUserLocation = true
    case .notDetermined:
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    default:
        print("Location Servies: Denied / Restricted")
    }
}
```

`checkLocationAuthorization` in `viewDidLoad`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

    self.checkLocationAuthorization()
}
```

You must also update the authorization status, when a `CLLocationManagerDelegate.locationManager(_:didChangeAuthorization:)` is occurred, you can *re-use* above method, like so:

```
extension GPSNewBin: CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        self.checkLocationAuthorization(authorizationStatus: status)
    }

}
```

When updating location in `didUpdateLocations`, use the updated user location sent in `userLocation.coordinate`, like so:

```
extension GPSNewBin: MKMapViewDelegate {

    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didUpdate userLocation: MKUserLocation) {
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: userLocation.coordinate, latitudinalMeters: 600, longitudinalMeters: 600)
        mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    }

}
```